# Google Calendar Addon on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have created a Google Calendar Add-on which can be accessed from Desktops and laptops. This now needs to be made available for users on mobile as well. As per [Google Calendar Add-on Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar), Calendar add-ons are not available on mobile clients.

Is there any way to access the add-on on mobile, other than extending it into a Gmail Add-on ?

P.S. :-

1. As this question is more on Google Product feature availability, I am not having any relevant codes here to share.
2. I had already posted this same question in [Google Support group](https://support.google.com/a/thread/194841304/how-can-we-use-calendar-add-ons-in-mobile). However, have not recieved any response there yet.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation you referenced](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar) seems quite clear on this:

> You can't yet use Calendar add-ons on mobile clients.

#### Feature request:

In this case, I'd consider requesting this feature on Google Issue Tracker using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus. I have submitted the request using the template you shared.